# bash-script tag doesn't work on unix stackexchange

Tags: support, tags

I've filed two questions recently on unix stackexchange and for both I noticed that one of the tags I used `bash-script` does not become an actual tag for the question.

Comment: That's because bash is a shell, and any bash script is a shell script in essence, so, [both are synonyms](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/shell-script/synonyms).

Comment: Thank you @Braiam, if you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bash-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash-script) is a synonym of the more general tag [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script): you can use `bash-script` as a tag name, but it's automatically rewritten to `shell-script`. If you enter both, you'll only end up with [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script).

Many questions about writing shell scripts don't depend on the exact shell being used, so [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) is good enough. If your question is specifically about a bash feature, use [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) and [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash).